# How to get rid of Serialization in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jquery-mobile

I have created a jQuery code which will take a form(which is in my view) and it will serialize it and it will post that to my controller.......Jquery code looks like this......

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {

                var jsonObj = $('#form').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Home/Index",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "cus": jsonObj }),
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data + "done");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Error!!!!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This is how my controller method looks like:..........

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Customer cus)
{
   string str = null;
   if (cus.Name == "jude")
        str = "Success";
   else
        str = "Error!!";
   return Json(str);
}
```

Now i need to undo the serialization inside my controller method......can someone please give me an idea to do this..........
I have tried two ways to do this but didn't work.....

```
1 - var model = (Customer)cus.Deserialize(); 
2 - JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var cus1 = js.Deserialize<Customer>(cus);
```

Comment: It just serializes to JSON right? So use `json_decode`.

Comment: Interesting question, but why do you feel the need to serialize/deserialize the form instead of just returning the view from the controller?

Comment: because if i just say passing an object from the view ..... after the last object parameter it will show me letters that i havan't insert.... for example if i put my customers name as Jude, it will show me "Jude/}".....

Comment: can you show me  an example to use json_decode please?